# Requisição ajax cancelada pelo navegador

Tags: ajax

Estou usando um plugin para múltiplos uploads de imagens, o [kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput). No meu localhost está funcionando sem nenhum problema mas quando mando a aplicação para o servidor e tento fazer upload das imagens, após a sexta imagem as requisições estão sendo canceladas e retornando a seguinte mensagem:

```
Provisional headers are shown
```

Eu não sei o que fazer, não sei como corrigir. Pesquisei sobre a mensagem no Google mas também não me ajudou muito. Imaginei que seria alguma coisa com o servidor ou a conexão, então disponibilizei meu localhost em rede e testei em outro computador, dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: já tentou em tab anónima, só para eliminar a hipótese de ser algum addon interferindo?

Comment: Sim, já tentei. O erro continua :(

Comment: Poderia postar o código de como está fazendo o _upload_ das imagens? Talvez possa ajudar melhor.

Comment: @AmandaLima conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Comment: Não consegui, resolvi usar outra forma de upload.